# Adding MediaPlayer.framework to my project when using CocoaPods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to add MediaPlayer.framework to my application but I don't see the ability to add a framework in the project but there is no Build Phases section.

I am using CocoaPods so it must do something differently with the project.

What is the correct way to add iOS frameworks when using CocoaPods?

Screenshot when trying to add frameworks to Pods project:

[image: Pods error]

here are screenshots:

[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What Xcode version are you using?

Comment: Xcode 5 latest on Mac OS X 10.9 for ios 7

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your project settings (build settings etc.) and the list of targets?

Comment: I have added screenshots

Answer (score 0):

You **should not** modify the Pods project. Too add a framework, add it to your project like this:

[image]

Comment: I don't have the BuildPhases option for my non Pod Project. I ended up not using CocoaPods and I was able to get it to work.